# How do I read epub file in a .Net web application using C# for the Reading API?

Tags: c#, rest, api, web-applications

I have searched for codes to read epub file on my .Net web application with no result. I intend to write the read method as an API which will accept the epub file as a **base64string** and **convert** it back **to epub** format for reading.
I have read about some Libraries that can read epubs but couldn't get a good documentation on how to use them for a web application.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? There is no built-in api for reading epub files, other than streams and helper classes to do reading of integers and so on.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "accept the epub file as a base64string"? You mean a simple base64-encoded byte array? If so, wouldn't your job of writing it back to "epub format" be to simply decode the base64 string back into a byte array?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen no, I mean to convert the base64stringed epub file I get from my Database and make it a readable epub file (by The ePub reader method) which will be returned to the front-end.

Comment: So isn't that what I said in the second comment? Decode the base64 string into a byte array and return that to the reader?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thank you so much. Now I get your point. I have already done the conversion to byte[ ], but the main issue I'm having is reading the byte [] file===> The reader method is the problem. Any help?

Comment: "the reader method", since you haven't posted this I have no clue what that even means.

Comment: A google search for ".net nuget epub" returned quite a few matches. Surely some of those would work. If you are helll bent of rolling your own epub lib, start off with knowldedge that epub is basically a zip container. You can open it with any unzip utility. From there, look up the epub specification. Also, beware that alot of epubs out in the wild do not exactly conform to the html restrictions in the spec. Or maybe the spec has changed now, it's been almost 10 years since I looked at it.

Comment: @AvoNappo, Thanks so much